# Can't see my webapp on my domain name even after adding DNS CNAME record

Tags: web, heroku, dns

I have added my heroku DNS CNAME record to my domain but my domain is also pointed to some nameserver. Is that why I can't see my webapp on my domain?

Comment: Congratulations on your first question! It will help you get better answers to provide some more technical details. Also, it helps if you show the steps and/or command-line output.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.